# sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near ":"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Here's my query:

```
QUERY = """
        UPDATE my_table
        SET
            my_prop=:foo
        WHERE hello='world'
"""
```

I execute the statement like this:

```
sqlalchemy_engine.execute(QUERY, foo='bar')
```

When I do I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near ":"
UPDATE my_table\n        SET\n            my_prop.foo = :foo
                                                         ^
```

I've never run into problems before passing values into the SQL Alchemy execute. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is not how you use parameters in `psycopg2`. Also what are you trying to do by setting a table name to something else?

Comment: sorry, meant to set a column. please see edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I've never run into problems before passing values into the SQLAlchemy execute. What am I doing wrong?

You might have been using [`Session.execute()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute) before, instead of [`Engine.execute()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.execute). The former automatically wraps SQL strings with the [`text()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) construct, or at least it behaves as such, which is the key here; it is `text()` that provides the DB-API driver independent handling of bound parameters/placeholders. Without it you're at the whims of your DB-API, [as noted by Craig Ringer in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47193568/2681632).

So in order to use `:name` style placeholders with an engine directly, simply wrap your query with `text()`:

```
sqlalchemy_engine.execute(text(QUERY), foo='bar')
```

Note that an engine [is the starting point](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html) of an SQLAlchemy app and everything builds on top of it, so that might be the reasoning behind one not doing the automatic wrapping, while the other does. A Session is a higher level abstraction.

Answer (score 4):

`psycopg2` doesn't support `:named` parameters. [The Python DB-API spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) allows for `:named` parameters with `paramstyle = 'named'`, but `psycopg2` uses:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> psycopg2.paramstyle
'pyformat'
```

[as documented in the `psycopg2` docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

It's a pity that Python's DB-API allows a variety of parameter styles, but that's how it is. Some drivers appear to support changing `paramstyle` as a DB-API extension. But it doesn't look like `psycopg2` is one of them:

```
>>> psycopg2.paramstyle = 'named'
>>> psycopg2.paramstyle
'named'
>>> cur.execute("SELECT :a, :b, :c", {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: SELECT :a, :b, :c

>>> conn.rollback()
>>> cur.execute("SELECT %(a)s, %(b)s, %(c)s", {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
>>>
```

So if you've seen `:param` style parameters work before, it's because some outer layer (maybe SQLAlchemy) is adapting your queries for you. A quick look at the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) suggests that [it may do just that](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#specifying-bound-parameter-behaviors).

At a guess, you're bypassing the SQLAlchemy dialect layer with your current code. But I don't really know SQLAlchemy...

Comment: In the end what's missing is just the `text()` wrapper around QUERY, which would handle the :name style in a DB-API independent fashion. Some methods such as `Session.execute()` actually do that automatically, but not so for `Engine.execute()`.